# Lytebox showing "about:blank" instead of required link

Tags: javascript, lytebox

I'm having this frustrating issue. I have the same exact code for 3 links that I call using Lytebox.

The links are as follows :

- resources.php?cat=Client Achievments [This works fine]
- resources.php?cat=Book Recommendations [This works fine]
- resources.php?cat=Savings Ideas [This does NOT work and loads a
  blank page, specifically, about:blank]

When I open the page in the browser without going through lytebox, it opens fine. But for some reason when I call that last link through the the javascript, it doesn't complete the process of loading the same page.

Thanks very much for your help!

-Aethon

Comment: Spaces in URLs are evil. Anyway, post some code, otherwise we cannot help you find the bug

Comment: Try replacing the link with `resources.php?cat=Savings%20Ideas` spaces in urls should be replaced with `%20`

Comment: Thanks for your comments, however, on resources.php, I have a URL decode, but this doesn't explain why the first 2 work (with spaces as well).

Comment: I added the %20 just in case but it still didn't work.  There is something odd going on here.

Comment: Hey Stefano, what code is required besides what I've put?  It's a standard call to Lytebox that works for every other case except this one.

Comment: Well, I worked around it.  I removed the word "savings" and it worked fine.  For some reason, that word was a no-no.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs when in the url appear some word like '**avi**', '**mpeg**', '**mpeg**', '**mov**', or '**wmv**'. In your case Savings contains 'avi'.